# When using Identity Impersonate I cannot access my local ASPNETDB.MDF database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a ASP.Net website that interacts with Dynamic CRM. It's also uses a local ASPNETDB.MDF for forms authentication.

For the CRM I need to impersonate the identity created on the domain for this purpose. When identity impersonate is enabled I no longer have access to the local Membership Database. How can I allow the domain user used for the impersonation access to the membership database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply add full control to that identity for the mdf file?

Comment: I have done that, including the folder structure that contains it. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean under "I no longer have access to the local Membership Database"?

Then, in a manner how you formulate I can guess that access to database is not local but remote. You should understand that the term "impersonation" has sense only for local access. In remote access the term "delegation" is used.

I can only advise you to search on impersonation vs. delegation in context of ASP.NET, IIS and SQL Server.
Related terms are "double hop", Kerberos, SPN (Service Principal Name), etc.

You may want to start from
  - [How To: Use Impersonation and Delegation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx)
  - [ASP.NET Identity Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649264.aspx)

though this is a matter of taste, context, etc. and I think you easily find more suitable for your context and understanding articles.